# remote connection and graphic problem

Tags: network, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I  need to be able to remote control many headless (without monitor) macs.
All the macs are on different locations, on different networks and with different router settings.
These are the informations i have *at any moment* about every machine:

- Computer name
- Local IP Address
- Public IP Address

BUT I cannot access the router confirguration those devices connect to (for, like port forwarding).

I tried several free services (my company does not want to spend money on commercial applications) like Chrome Remote Desktop and DWService but hey all have problems rendering the pages.

Since the macs are headless, the graphic card does not kick-in, resulting in a lot of white windows and many GUI being unavailable (like many elements of the menubar)

I could use HDMI dummy plugs that simulte a monitor, solving the issue of blank windows, but still that would require my company to spend ~6 $ for each machine and they asked me to find a solution, if there is, to do that without extra hw.

I spent the last three days finding for a solution, without success.
But maybe some of you guys can direct me to a solution, if there is one!

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest TeamViewer. Keep on running TeamViewer on end-user, and always connect from your machine with the TeamViewer ID.

Comment: @udhy TeamViewer isn't free for commercial use. If the company doesn't want to spend $6 for an HDMI dongle they probably also don't want to spend much much more on a TeamViewer license.

Comment: Did you explain to your management that the $6 x #machines is cheaper than letting you search for a free solution for yet another week?

Comment: @nohillside: I totally agree with you. It has a personal one too (which is a kind free) and the company doesn't want to spend 6$, also looking for better solution without charge, so just gave an alternative. Even personal one will be detected in a few days if it is used for commercial, and then it terminates the connection within couple of minutes every time.

Comment: I agree with you, even though it doesn't help find a solution. But I also understand the concern of a startup that needs to plan the future. And if business goes well they might have several hundreds of machines. Therefore 6 euro a machine is not irrelevant. And investing some time for a proper research to save future spending is not that unreasonable, if you ask me.

Comment: Well, €6 per machine is less then the person sitting in front of it earns per hour, and way less the machine will cost.

Comment: Once again, the scenario of buying one of the most expensive computers on the market is juxtaposed with being a curmudgeon and balking at a solution that literally costs only a few dollars and searching  for (only) a free solution.  This is called being penny wise and pound foolish.

Answer (score 3):

Buy the dongles. I worry your company is able to secure these if it isn’t budgeting for training and support let alone very inexpensive adapters.

There’s being frugal and then there’s “we’re not even thinking about selling one Mac” to fund to what needed to run the rest of the fleet.

If your labor is cheap, make cakes and cookies and sell them to fund your business. Good luck, I don’t mean to insult, but the reasoning in your question doesn’t add up.

Also, solve your network issue - the business and you are toast if you can’t get control of the network (we’re back to security and priorities).

Comment: This can’t be upvoted enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer bmike.
I agree that solving the network issue is vital, that’s why we are  investing time in making it secure and affordable for a startup.
I love the selling cake idea, but we’ll stick with teamviewer, since 30 USD a month is better than 6USD dongles for each machine.
I appreciate your time replying me, it’s always unvaluable have some expert’s view on topics you are not still familiar with.
When I’ll be more informed, while trying to help others, I’ll try not to be patronizing though