# Apple Remote Desktop over internet "without" port forwarding

Tags: remote-desktop, router, apple-remote-desktop

Is it possible using Apple Remote Desktop to connect to computers over the internet (so different networks) ** *without* ** having to tweak the router settings of those devices?

PS currently using both Mojave and Catalina

Comment: Does your router use NAT? That’s the only reason you can’t remote in. Does your router allow VPN? Another reason for this. It seems [you’re asking a network question and not an ARD question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379183/).

Comment: If you have SSH access to a public server, you could probably set up SSH remote forwarding (which is the opposite of local forwarding -- https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example#remote-forwarding ) for ARD's ports.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, not any more. It used to be possible using Back to my Mac, which was abandoned at Mojave.

See [Does Apple Remote Desktop connect to computers over the internet?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107399/does-apple-remote-desktop-connect-to-computers-over-the-internet?rq=1) for how it used to work.

Also ref: [Wikipedia - Back to my Mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_My_Mac)

Answer (score 2):

Not a total solution but I use [Teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/) now where I used to use ARD. It works without router tweaking and is easy to set up at the remote end.

Comment: TeamViewer and all other manner of screen sharing bypass NAT. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a VPN to connect to your remote network. it's better for everyone involved

Comment: ARD works just the same way as a VPN… in so much as the other end must be ready to accept it.

Comment: I would say VPN implies an addressable IP address gets provisioned. ARD never assigns them so it’s really Apples/Oranges - they don’t even do the same thing @Tetsujin

Comment: you're right I was just saying from a security perspective, using VPN is a better overall strategy than trying to "open up ports" on your router, map them to the machine you want to control, etc. They do NOT do the same thing, but when used TOGETHER they work great.

Comment: also I haven't needed a static IP in 25 years since I'm a very happy DynDNS customer and most routers today have built-in DDNS (I recommend you get one that does and set it up-- works great)